# Socket.io client in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, websocket, socket.io

I want to build a microservice infrastructure with nodejs services and a master service, the communication between these services should happen via socket.io, i've setup my socket.io server, but their browser client (socket.io-client) is not working in nodejs (i guess it uses some browser only APIs). Is there a way to create a nodejs socket.io (NOT WEBSOCKETS) client?

**EDIT**

My client side code:

```js
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io("127.0.0.1:3000");

socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log(socket.id);
});

socket.on("disconnect", () => {
  console.log(socket.id);
});
```

My server side code:

```js
import { Server } from "socket.io";
const io = new Server();

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(socket)
});

io.listen(3000);
```

Both are written in typescript, the package versions are:

socket.io: ^4.4.0

socket.io-client: ^4.4.0

The Problem is, that i don't get any logs in my console, so i think there is something wrong with client, because socket.io does not mention node in there client side compatiblity graph.

[image]

Comment: There is a socket.io-client [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) specifically for nodejs.  I've used it.  It works.

Comment: If something isn't work for you in that library, I'd suggest you post your code and explain what isn't working.  Chances are there's something wrong with your code or your environment, not the library.

Comment: i've used their typescript code from the offical documentation for servers and clients. https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/ and https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-initialization/

Comment: I repeat.  If it's not working for you, then post your code and explain what isn't working.  It's NOT a problem with the library.  It's a problem with your code or your environment.  We cannot help without seeing your code.  I'm not sure how you expect us to "guess" what your problem might be without seeing your code.

Comment: Hey :) Sorry for not providing enough information, hope my edit fixed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have to pass a valid URL here:

```
const socket = io("127.0.0.1:3000");
```

I have no idea why socket.io doesn't give you an error, but if you change that to:

```
const socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:3000");
```

Then, it will work.

---

If you set `DEBUG=socket.io-client` in your environment, it won't show you an error, but it will show you that it's trying to connect to:

```
undefined//127.0.0.1:3000
```

which would give you a clue, I guess.

If you set `DEBUG=*` in your environment, you will get a lot more debug info (so much that it's a bit hard to sort through).

---

Set [Logging and Debugging Socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v3/logging-and-debugging/) for more info.

Comment: Works like it should! Thanks, i'm also currious why there is no error.

Comment: @unterstrichserver - There is a `connect_error` event, but you weren't listening for it.  Also, see the notes I added to my answer about debug flags that get you a lot more debug info.